# What standard library function does libc.a contain?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, glibc, standard-library

When using `gcc` under Linux, one does not need to add command-line options to use standard library functions like `printf`. In book *An Introduction to GCC*, it explains *"The C standard library itself is stored in ‘/usr/lib/libc.a’ and contains functions speciﬁed in the
ANSI/ISO C standard, such as ‘printf’—this library is linked by default for every C program."*
But one has to add `-lm` in the command-line to use standard library functions declared in `math.h`, since `libm.a` is not linked against in default. 
So which standard library functions are included in `libc.a`, thus do not require to link other library files. And other than `libm.a`, are there any other standard library functions that need to explicitly add library files to link against, and what are the file names of the library?

Comment: You can use the nm command to find out what a library contains.

Comment: @JimBalter Is there a way to get better results than just a pile of object symbols?

Comment: Select defined external symbols. But really, you don't need that ... libc.a contains everything except those things that are explicitly stated to need another library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libc` and `libm` both handle all ANSI/ISO functions.  Beyond that, Linux and UNIX systems follow POSIX, which includes `libpthread` (usually linked in using the `-pthread` option, not explicitly linking in the library), as well as `libiconv` which may be included in `libc`.  Additional libraries in POSIX include `curses` and `libutil` for miscellaneous functions.